# AuthenticationProperties is null in ChallengeAsync?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authentication

I have an IAuthenticationHandler service in my asp core app that handles the authentication process.
In AuthenticateAsync I have the following code:

```
var props = new AuthenticationProperties();
props.SetParameter(PARAM_AUTHTYPE, m_authScheme);
var result = AuthenticateResult.Fail("Cookie authentication is not sufficient.", props);
return Task.FromResult(result);
```

Basically I want to pass m_authScheme to the ChallengeAsync method.

Now in the ChallengeAsync I have:

```
public Task ChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties? properties)
```

The properties argument is always null. What am I missing?

Comment: If you added [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it would be easier to tell. I'm not sure, at this stage.